# Regular update of Bootstrap navbar items with jquery ajax fetching data from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write a webchat using boostrap, jquery ajax and php.
[image]

The page is divided in two sections:

- on the left: menu containing all people I'm chatting to.
  I'm currently using a bootstrap navbar for the menu. Each element (nav-item -- which I refer to as 'header' below) is generated from a jquery ajax to a php file which gets the information from an SQL database.
  `<div id="allchatsheaders"></div>`
- on the right: the conversation associated to the selected 'header'.
  I'm using another jquery ajax to another php file which gets the information from an SQL database.
  `<div id="current_conversation"></div>`

It brings all sorts of unwanted behaviours when I define a regular refresh with the function:

```
setInterval(refresh_chats_headers, 5000);
```

(I've not even tried to set the setInterval to the refresh_chats_messages() function yet -- topic for another day)

My jquery ajax is:

```
function refresh_chats_headers() {

    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_chats_headers.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{ },
        success:function(response)
        {
            $('#allchatsheaders').html(response);
            
            //when user clicks on header, we refresh the conversation
            $('.nav-item > a').click(function(){ 
                var header_id = $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1];
                refresh_chats_current_conversation(header_id);
            }
        });
}
```

My php is:

```
print("<li class='nav-item'>
           <a href='#chattab-".$headerlist[$i]."' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action' data-bs-toggle='pill'>
              blablabla
           </a>
       </li>
");
```

If the user clicks on one item ('header') in the menu, it unselects it when the ajax is called again by setInterval.

So I tried another way by parsing the header_id of the selected item to the php file which then sets the 'active' keyword to the corresponding header.

```
var current_headerid_selected = 0;
function refresh_chats_headers() {

    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_chats_headers.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{ h_headerid:current_headerid_selected },
        success:function(response)
        {
            $('#allchatsheaders').html(response);

            //when user clicks on header, we refresh current_headerid_selected 
            //and the conversation
            $('.nav-item > a').click(function(){
                var header_id = $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1];
                current_headerid_selected = header_id;
                refresh_chats_current_conversation(header_id);                  
            });
    });
}
```

My php is:

```
print("<li class='nav-item'>");
if ($curr_headerid == $headerlist[$i])
    print("
        <a href='#chattab-".$headerlist[$i]."' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 active' data-bs-toggle='pill'>
    ");
else
    print("
        <a href='#chattab-".$headerlist[$i]."' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0' data-bs-toggle='pill'>
    ");

print("              blablabla

        </a>
    </li>");
```

Here if the user clicks on one item ('header') in the menu, it 'keeps' it selected when the ajax is called again by setInterval.
However, when the user clicks on a different item, random things happen.

I now struggle to find a solution.
Any idea?

Comment: In your second attempt I can see that you send `h_headerid` through to the PHP. But it's unclear, from your PHP snippet, how you're reading that into the PHP or using it. Do you define `$curr_headerid = $_POST["h_headerid"];` somewhere before the code you've shown us? Have you verified using your browser's developer tools and some PHP debugging whether the correct value is being sent to the server in the AJAX request, and whether PHP can see it?

Comment: P.S. As a more general point, AJAX isn't a great solution for a live chat function. You have to refresh at intervals so you don't get instant updates, and it doesn't scale well at all when lots of users are all trying to refresh their data. Using websockets to provide 2-way instant communication between the client and server would provide a much nicer UX and a more performant application. That is now (and has been for some time) the standard way to implement this kind of feature.

Comment: @ADyson: Thanks for getting back to me. I indeed define $curr_headerid = $_POST["h_headerid"]; at the beginning of my php file. Whilst debugging I could see that the value was parsed properly but as there is a lag between the parsing and the display of the information, the user could click in between this lag time and therefore unwanted behaviours occur. As for the websockets, that's precious information, thank you. I've never looked into these but it sounds like I'll have to.

Comment: It occurs to me that instead of trying to set this in the PHP, you should actually just set it in the Javascript, when the AJAX request returns. That way if the user has changed the selected item in the meantime, the JS variable which stores that fact would have been updated, and so hopefully it would select the right one. The only question I guess would be: what if the selected item is not returned by the PHP? is that a possible situation? e.g. a chat could be deleted or something?

Comment: Also, regardless of whether you use sockets or not, a cleaner design would have all the HTML rendering done on the browser side, and the server would just return some JSON describing the current state of the chat data. That way you wouldn't have to worry about what HTML the server returns. You'd just get a list of current chats, and then the browser has to decide how to display that on screen, and what to mark active etc.